# CORS not working even headers set in server

Tags: java, angularjs, cors

I'm using AngularJS to send request to Java backend.

In AngularJS, I'm doing like this way:

```
     return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8180/sample/user',
            data: userData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
            .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("Request failed with status: " + status);
            });
```

**The AngularJS app is running at localhost:8000** through http-server command:

```
http-server -a localhost -p 8000
```

And in Java backend side, I added a filter and in the filter I set headers:

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE,PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

This Java Application is running at localhost tomcat server: **localhost:8180**

But I'm still getting the CORS error complains in chrome's console:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.**

And I found in Response's header:

```
Allow:POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 25 Aug 2015 18:19:46 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Does anyone know the reason the cross domain request fails even I set the headers?

And in app.js, I also have this settings:

```
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

===========================================================================

Finally I resolved this issue by adding a filter from this [link](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html)

And I have added an answer below, hope this can also help someone else who has the similar issue.

Comment: Do you have an interceptor, if yes put it there $http.defaults.useXDomain = true; otherwise, add that when you make the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many approaches mentioned in this post, and finally I resolved it in another way: I added filter in web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and I added dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
         <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can also check out this [CORS Filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it with chrome, there is a bug ([info](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743)) that will make localhost not match with the CORS headers. If you are just testing your application, you can use the domain `lvh.me` that will point to `127.0.0.1` (same as localhost). Or, as the last response in the link says, start chrome with a flag, `--disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add cors definition to your server web.xml definition? I am configuring CORS via web.xml and it is working perfectly.

> This filter is an implementation of W3C's CORS (Cross-Origin Resource
>   Sharing) specification, which is a mechanism that enables cross-origin
>   requests.
>
> The filter works by adding required Access-Control-* headers to
>   HttpServletResponse object. The filter also protects against HTTP
>   response splitting. If request is invalid, or is not permitted, then
>   request is rejected with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden). A flowchart
>   that demonstrates request processing by this filter is available.
>
> The minimal configuration required to use this filter is:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The link is : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: I tried this, and I also added dependency for this, but i still got the error